# Update script to new element injected into DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom

I have a list with sublists and a < select> box.
Everytime I change the select box, I need to RELOAD this list with the new
parameter (selected value).

I'm using ajax to get the new data, then I remove the list, and inject the new element (same list with new data) into DOM.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#selectSemestres').change(function(obj){        
        var anoSemestre = $(this).val();        
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '{{ route('professor') }}',
            data: {anoSemestre: anoSemestre},
            success: function(data){
                var lista = $(data).find('#list-professores'); //Get only the new professor list and thier disciplines
                $('#list-professores').remove(); //Remove old list
                $('#professores').append(lista); //Append the new list where the old list was before.
                load_js();
                $('.prof-disciplinas').sortable({
                    connectWith: '.prof-disciplinas'});
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

The problem is: When you insert a new element to the dom, you need to "reload" your javascript so it would recognize the new element. That's what I do with `load_js()` method.

```
function load_js()
{
   var head= document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
   var script= document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript'; 
    script.src  = 'js/script.js';
   head.appendChild(script);
}
```

But I have another `<script > ... </script>` inside the same .php file that I need to RELOAD it so it would work with this new list:

#### Script that I need to reload and use Drag&Drop with the new list

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        var oldTeacherId;
        $('.prof-disciplinas').sortable({
            connectWith: '.prof-disciplinas',

            start: function (event, ui){
                oldTeacherId = ui.item.parent().prev().prev().attr('data-id');
            },
            stop: function (event, ui){

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '{{ URL::to("/professor") }}',
                    data: { 
                        disciplina: ui.item.attr('data-id'),
                        professor: ui.item.parent().prev().prev().attr('data-id'),
                        old: oldTeacherId 
                    },
                    success: function(data){
                        swal("Good job!", "You clicked the button!", "success"); 
                        //Atualizar tabela aqui
                        var evento = $('#calendario').fullCalendar('clientEvents', function(event){

                            return event.id == $(ui.item).attr('data-id');
                        });
                        evento[0].backgroundColor = '' + getCor( ui.item.parent().prev().prev().attr('data-id'));
                        $('#calendario').fullCalendar('updateEvent', evento[0]);
                    },
                    error: function(){

                    }

            });
        }
    });
    });
</script>
```

This Drag&Drop effect is not working after ajax.
How may I reload that piece of script ? Make it recognize and work with the new inserted list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's completely wrong way to achieve things in JavaScript.

Let's start with first example:

```
$('#selectSemestres').change(function(obj){...})
```

Could be replaced with:

```
$('body').on('change', '#selectSemestres', function(obj){...})
```

http://api.jquery.com/on/

As for your second piece of code, you can extract it into a separate function, and call it every time you need to reload your data:

```js
var oldTeacherId;
function reloadTeachers() {
  $('.prof-disciplinas').sortable({
    connectWith: '.prof-disciplinas',

    start: function(event, ui) {
      oldTeacherId = ui.item.parent().prev().prev().attr('data-id');
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '{{ URL::to("/professor") }}',
        data: {
          disciplina: ui.item.attr('data-id'),
          professor: ui.item.parent().prev().prev().attr('data-id'),
          old: oldTeacherId
        },
        success: function(data) {
          swal("Good job!", "You clicked the button!", "success");
          //Atualizar tabela aqui
          var evento = $('#calendario').fullCalendar('clientEvents', function(event) {

            return event.id == $(ui.item).attr('data-id');
          });
          evento[0].backgroundColor = '' + getCor(ui.item.parent().prev().prev().attr('data-id'));
          $('#calendario').fullCalendar('updateEvent', evento[0]);
        },
        error: function() {

        }

      });
    }
  });
}

$(function() {
  reloadTeachers(oldTeacherId);
});
```

Note that using global variables is a bad practice, and oldTeacherId should be encapsulated in the final solution.

Comment: The second piece of code is the Drag&Drop effect. If I give a `function name()` to it, it wont auto-load with the page load. How may I achieve that? I need to load it with the pageLoad and also reload it when the ajax happens. Also, I don't see why the first part is wrong, could you explain to me please?

Comment: Please check again my example. I don't simply give name to the anonymous function. I call the new function from it. Passing function to $() will execute it on load. Then you can call reloadTeachers whenever you need to.

Comment: Dude, you rock ! Working so beautiful !  
 Just one more thing, could you teach me why the way I was doing  `$('#selectSemestre').change()` is a wrong way to do it ?

Comment: You've to use the **event delegation** `on()` when you deal with fresh DOM added dynamically to the page by script.

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro the way you did it meant that change will occur only for elements that are on the page when the page is loaded. Since you recreate your elements, that didn't help. "On" makes sure that even if you add elements later, the event will still happen on them.